Sequential probability ratio test for variance
An exercise problem from Hogg and McKean's book "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics" is the following
Exercise 8.4.1. Let $X$ be $N(0,\theta)$ and, in the notation of this section, let $\theta' = 4,$ $\theta'' = 9,$ $\alpha_a = 0.05,$ and $\beta_a = 0.10.$ Show that the sequential probability ratio test can be based upon the statistic $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2.$ Determine $c_0(n)$ and $c_1(n).$
Note that both null and alternative are simple hypothesis (i.e $H_0: \theta = \theta'$ and $H_1: \theta = \theta''$).
Solution is straightforward and we get the answer to be $$5.8387n - 32.4186 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \leq 5.8387n+41.6214$$ as in we cannot make a decision as long as $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ is bounded that way. Once it "escapes" one of the bounds, we make a decision and stop taking more samples.
My question: The lower bound (the so called $c_0(n)$) is negative till $n=6$!! We will never be able to accept the null till the sixth sample is taken. My first reaction to this  was "Doesn't this increase the chance that we reject the null even though the null is true?" but then I also observed that the upper bound is quite high and keeps going up by $5.8387$ for every additional sample taken.
Nevertheless it is still true that in this case, the sequential test cannot make a decision that null is true (when the null is in fact true) till a certain number of samples is reached. In fact we might as well start with $n=6$. Is my thinking correct?
